# what is the difference between the following two in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am assigning php values to javascript as following

```
var a = <?php echo 39; ?>
```

but javascript is throwing following error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".
When I am assigning php values in the following way then I am not getting any problem

```
var a = "<?php echo 39; ?>";
```

What I think is php code runs on server side first.So in the first case the php code is executed on server side first then that executed code is sent to the browser.So browser should see that code as(i think)

```
var a=39;
```

but instead of that it is throwing error.Why is it happening?

Comment: You're sure the error isn't what follows this variable, and that you just need a semicolon after the PHP echo ?

Answer (score 3):

Your 1st example misses the semicolon off the end of the javascript variable assignment:

```
var a = <?php echo 39; ?>; //<-- missing semicolon
```

Comment: It's not missing per se, semi colons aren't always required, it depends on what comes after.

Comment: Arent' semicolon optionnal in Javascript?

Comment: Yes they are @D4V1D, but as adeneo said, it depends on what comes after that line.

Comment: yeah.if i provide semicolon it is working fine.but the second case is working fine eventhough we ar en't providing semicolon.

Comment: @SivaCharan Huh? Thats not what the code in your question suggests: `var a = "<?php echo 39; ?>"; //<-- look a semicolon`

Comment: i checked by removing the semicolon after the statement for second case and it is working fine

Comment: @SivaCharan Well without seeing the generated javascript its hard to tell - edit your question to include the generated javascript in both cases, including the following line as well

Comment: They are also two different types, integer and string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's best practice to always end your statements with a semicolon. But regardless of the discussion in the other answers about where and when you should have one, there is also another very important difference in the two examples you have provided.

Example 1:

```
var a = <?php echo 39; ?>
```

Variable `a` is now an **integer** (no quotes):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29

Example 2:

```
var a = "<?php echo 39; ?>";
```

Variable `a` is now a **string** (quotes):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29

I would say that the different between variable types is something you should be aware of. Especially in Javascript!